# How to get meta tags value from search engine optimization in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

¿How to read meta tags in SharePoint 2013 in every page with friendly url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found the answer debuggin, this work for me.

```
public class SEOProperties {

    public string PropBrowserTitle          { get; set; }
    public string PropBrowserDescription    { get; set; }
    public string PropBrowserKeyWords       { get; set; }
    public string PropBrowserSiteNoIndex    { get; set; }

}

    private SEOProperties GetSEOProperties(){

    SEOProperties SEO = new SEOProperties();
    if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    Guid siteGuid   = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
                    Guid webGuid    = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;

                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteGuid))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            TaxonomySession session     = new TaxonomySession(site);
                            NavigationTerm  navTermino  = TaxonomyNavigationContext.Current.NavigationTerm;
                            Term            termino     = navTermino.GetTaxonomyTerm(session);

                            var SEOPropBrowserTitle = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropBrowserTitle").SingleOrDefault();
                            var SEOPropDescription  = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropDescription").SingleOrDefault();
                            var SEOPropKeyWords     = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropKeywords").SingleOrDefault();
                            var SEOPropSiteNoIndex  = termino.LocalCustomProperties.Where(o => o.Key == "_Sys_Seo_PropSitemapNoIndex").SingleOrDefault();

                            SEO.PropBrowserDescription  = SEOPropDescription.Value;
                            SEO.PropBrowserKeyWords     = SEOPropKeyWords.Value;
                            SEO.PropBrowserSiteNoIndex  = SEOPropSiteNoIndex.Value;
                            SEO.PropBrowserTitle        = SEOPropBrowserTitle.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return SEO;
}
```